# Why does decreasing y position by 1 point causes the Text view to jump by 47 points when having the IgnoringSafeArea enabled in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, layout, position, absolute, safearea

I am trying to put a message on the blue line (the safe area box shown in the image). I need to have the .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all). The problem is that as soon as I change the Y position to anything under 11, the text jumps 47 points up to the position shown in the image. Does anybody know what is causing this jump?
I am putting both of the cases here with the resulting screenshot. I would appreciate it if anyone could help me understand why that 1-point difference in the Y position causes the "First" message to print 47 points higher than the "Second" message.

```
struct TestView: View {
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader{ geo in
        Text("First")
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            .position(x: 50, y: 10)
        Text("Second")
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            .position(x: 50, y: 11)
    }
}}
```

[image: Screenshot of the preview]

Comment: IMO the entire way is wrong... what do you actually try to achieve?

Comment: After some struggle, I found a workaround to my original problem. The question is about understanding the basics of the layout. I studied multiple documents. I am still not able to figure out the reason for this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

If I’m not mistaken it’s the order of the modifiers.  Everything after edgesIgnoringSafeArea still ignores Safe area.

That modifier wrapped everything that came before it.